# How do I get to Google Code Playground?

Tags: google-playground

I use to be able to get to Google Code Playground page.

As discussed in 
[A guide to Google Code PlayGround](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3897406)

Its a web-based tool that lets web developers try out all of the APIs that Google provides, tweak the code, and see the results, I found it very useful.

But now when I try, I get redirected to [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/)!

Has anyone got any ideas why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google took the Code Playground down.

Comment: I too searched for it like for hours, No trace of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't *know* why they changed it, but probably you will need to go to the specific API/product you're looking for and search there.

For example, I used to teach the Visualization APIs with the playground, but these seem to have been reclassified as a chart "product" with the interactive code editing now hosted through JSFiddle:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

Good luck (re)locating what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks SusanEMcG, I found what I was looking for, but its a pity, I had found the playground  a useful tool for testing my own code!